# How to create custom Azure role which allows users to add access policies to Key Vaults?

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I'm creating a custom role for a Key Vault which will give users these abilities:

- generate/import ‘Keys, Secrets and Certificates'
- add new and manage existing access policies

We are seeking to follow the least privileged access principle, So I'm starting with the 'read' role and adding permissions on a granular basis to achieve minimum functionality.

I started with a clone of the read role and added `Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/accessPolicies/write` because it enables users to `Update an existing access policy by merging or replacing, or add a new access policy to a vault.`

But users to whom I assign this role say they cannot add access policies.  I don't see any other policy-related permissions available under Keyvault available.

I considered that perhaps they need `Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/write`, but that would enable users to create new vaults.

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Azure keyvault, there are management plane permission and data plane permission, if you want `add new and manage existing access policies`, the user who got the permission can add/update himself in the access policy, so actually it includes the `generate/import ‘Keys, Secrets and Certificates'`. So your goal is just `add new and manage existing access policies` in fact. And if you just want `generate/import` without e.g. `Get/List`, I think your requirement is conflicting.

To `add new and manage existing access policies`, the `Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/accessPolicies/write` is not enough, you also need `Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/write`. I test it with a user just got `Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/accessPolicies/write` permission in powershell [`Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy`](http://Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy), the error mentioned that.

[image]

So in your case, your option is to use custom role like below.

```
{
  "Name": "Keyvault test",
  "Id": "e00236fe-0057-4a8b-bfee-890f757c3d38",
  "IsCustom": true,
  "Description": "test",
  "Actions": [
    "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/read",
    "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/write",

  ],
  "NotActions": [],
  "DataActions": [],
  "NotDataActions": [],
  "AssignableScopes": [
    "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx"
  ]
}
```

> but that would enable users to create new vaults.

Don't worry about this, you just need to assign the user with the custom role at the specific keyvault scope (select a keyvault -> `Access control (IAM)`), he will not be able to create other keyvaults.

[image]